# Warning: compiled but with compilation errors in while creating trigger in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

The table of my project are.

```
create table book_rec(book_name char(30),author char(30),total_copies number(15),available_copies number(5),primary key(book_name));
create table membership_rec(mem_id number(20),mem_name char(30),no_of_books_taken number(4),primary key(mem_id));
create table book_details(book_id number(30),book_name char(30),mem_id number(5),primary key(book_id),foreign key(book_name)references book_rec(book_name));
create table circulation_rec(book_id number(20),mem_id number(20),issue_date date,return_date date,foreign key (book_id)references book_details(book_id),foreign key(mem_id)references membership_rec(mem_id));
```

I want to create a trigger to automatically increment and decrement the no_of_books_taken from the book_rec upon the issue_date and return_date based on the circulation_rec record.But the program shows the error.How can I resolve the error.Can you help anyone?

This is my code for trigger.

```
create or replace trigger t_trigger
After insert or update on  circulation_rec
for each row
begin

if inserting then
update book_rec
set available_copies = available_copies - 1 
where book_name = :NEW.book_name;
update membership_rec
set no_of_books_taken = no_of_books_taken +1
where mem_id = :NEW.mem_id;
elsif updating then
update book_rec
set available_copies = available_copies - 1 
where book_name = :old.book_name;
update membership_rec
set no_of_books_taken = no_of_books_taken - 1
where mem_id = :New.mem_id;
end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: What is the error? `show errors` should list them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `SHOW ERRORS` or run this query,

```
SELECT NAME, TYPE, line, text FROM user_errors;
```

You will get to know the full error message

```
NAME,       TYPE    LINE           TEXT
----        ---     ---            ----
T_TRIGGER   TRIGGER 6   PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.BOOK_NAME'
T_TRIGGER   TRIGGER 13  PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.BOOK_NAME'
```

Now, this error is caused because the owner of the Trigger -`circulation_rec` table does not have `book_name` columns.So,Oracle does not understand what `:NEW.book_name` and `:OLD.book_name` mean in this context and hence it throws bad bind variable error.

Now, to fix this you could add an `IN` condition to get the `book_id` from `book_details` table, because  `circulation_rec` does have `book_id`.

Something like this.

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER t_trigger 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON circulation_rec 
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF inserting THEN 
      UPDATE book_rec 
      SET    available_copies = available_copies - 1 
      WHERE  book_name IN (SELECT book_name 
                           FROM   book_details 
                           WHERE  book_id = :NEW.book_id); 

      UPDATE membership_rec 
      SET    no_of_books_taken = no_of_books_taken + 1 
      WHERE  mem_id = :NEW.mem_id; 
    ELSIF updating THEN 
      UPDATE book_rec 
      SET    available_copies = available_copies - 1 
      WHERE  book_name IN (SELECT book_name 
                           FROM   book_details 
                           WHERE  book_id = :OLD.book_id); 

      UPDATE membership_rec 
      SET    no_of_books_taken = no_of_books_taken - 1 
      WHERE  mem_id = :New.mem_id; 
    END IF; 
END; 

/
```

Here's a dbfiddle [**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=55cda7dc66b10b64ccad81c398b35b6b)